# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError using RxImagePicker

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to use RxImagePicker ([github link](https://github.com/MLSDev/RxImagePicker)) to choose or take photos in Android. It works fine on some devices, but when I try on a Samsung DUOS (API 16), it crashes. Stack trace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: rx.subjects.PublishSubject
at com.mlsdev.rximagepicker.RxImagePicker.requestImage(RxImagePicker.java:29)
at br.com.deway.imeeting.PortalColaborador.Login.Guardiao.GuardiaoActivity.pickImageFromSource(GuardiaoActivity.java:340)
at br.com.deway.imeeting.PortalColaborador.Login.Guardiao.GuardiaoActivity.access$200(GuardiaoActivity.java:80)
at br.com.deway.imeeting.PortalColaborador.Login.Guardiao.GuardiaoActivity$4.onClick(GuardiaoActivity.java:320)
at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:934)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1280)
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3071)
at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3971)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My code:

```
RxImagePicker.with(this).requestImage(source)
                .flatMap(uri -> RxImageConverters.uriToBitmap(getApplicationContext(), uri))
                .subscribe(result -> {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    result.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
                    byte[] bitmapData = bos.toByteArray();
                    encodedPhoto = Base64.encodeToString(bitmapData, Base64.DEFAULT);
                }, throwable -> {
                    showDialogWithoutFinish("Ocorreu um erro ao carregar a imagem, por favor tente novamente");
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

NoClassDefFound errors almost always mean you are missing a jar file in the classpath. It is interesting that this works on some machines and not others. I can think of two obvious possibilities:

1. This is code that is only accessed on some devices. You may have a surrounding conditional statement that checks for some property before running your code.
2. This is a compatibility issue. You will either need to download another version of the jar that works on DUOS, or DUOS does not support the RXImagePicker. If the latter is the case, you may need to make this step conditional and use another driver that is compatible with DUOS.

Comment: But when I download the source code from github and run the sample application, it works on DUOS. I tried everything, my code is the same from the sample, and yet it doesn't work

Comment: And your library folder and build files are also the same?

Comment: Yes, I got around this catching the exception and doing another way